# PasswordResetConfirmView doen't generate mail

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to set a "forgot password" link in my django application, using the default auth views but with my own templates inside an specific path. I was able to implement the reset form and the 'Done' wview , but aperantly the mail is not beeing generated. Not errors either.

This is my urls.py file:

```
path('password-reset/', PasswordResetView.as_view(
         template_name='auth/reset_password/reset.html',
         subject_template_name='auth/reset_password/mail_subject.txt',
         email_template_name='auth/reset_password/mail_body.html',
         success_url='/password-reset/done/'
     ), name='password_reset'),

path('password-reset/done/', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
         template_name='auth/reset_password/done.html'
     ), name='password_reset_done'),

path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
     PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
         template_name='auth/reset_password/confirm.html'
     ), name='password_reset_confirm'),

path('password-reset-complete/',
     PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
         template_name='auth/reset_password/complete.html'
     ), name='password_reset_complete'),
```

My mail_body.html:

```
{% autoescape off %}
  To initiate the password reset process for your {{ user.get_username }} TestSite Account,
  click the link below:{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
  If clicking the link above doesn't work, please copy and paste the URL in a new browser
  window instead.
  Sincerely,
  The Epicups Team
{% endautoescape %}
```

I'm thinking that maybe my user model my be the problem, since im using the mail as username, so here it is:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin): 

email= models.EmailField(_('email'), unique=True)
vat_number =  models.CharField(_('vat_number'), max_length=9)
company_name = models.CharField(_('company_name'), max_length=255)
contact_person = models.CharField(_('contact_person'), max_length=255)
host_id = models.CharField(_('host_id'), max_length=255, blank=True)
last_login_at = models.DateTimeField(_('last_login_at'), auto_now_add=True)
current_login_at = models.DateTimeField(_('current_login_at'), auto_now_add=True)
last_login_ip = models.CharField(_('last_login_ip'), max_length=100, blank=True)
current_login_ip = models.CharField(_('current_login_ip'), max_length=100, blank=True)
login_count = models.BigIntegerField(_('login_count'), null=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(_('is_active'), null=True)
confirmed_at = models.DateTimeField(_('current_login_at'), auto_now_add=True)
role_id = models.BigIntegerField(_('login_count'),  null=True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['vat_number','company_name','contact_person']

objects =  MyUserManager()
```

Is that possible? If so, i have no idea how to fix it. The success_url redirection is happening.

My settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'example@example.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify [`EMAIL_FIELD`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.EMAIL_FIELD) in your model:

```
EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['vat_number','company_name','contact_person']
```

Comment: @Xhark did you specify `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting?

Comment: @Xhark hm.. Did you specify email settings: EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT, DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL and other?

Comment: For know i just try to use the console

Comment: @Xhark I think even in this case you still need at least EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT and DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL values in settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206526/discussion-between-xhark-and-neverwalkaloner).